# Html. Text input cuts first character "j"

Tags: html, css, text, input, fonts

I have a `text input`:

```
<input type="text" name="test1" value="jj" style="padding:0px;font-size:70px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'">
```

But the first "j" character is not fully visible with `Times New Roman font-family`. What could be a problem?

[image]

**EDIT**

In my case `padding-left` does not help. I add `padding-left:30px` and the result is:

[image]

Comment: This is just how fonts work. With lead typefaces each character was positioned on a block. The same is true for digital type. The tail of `j` just want to be below the previous glyph. It is designed that way. So the tail of j has a negative x coordinate. Do fight your font, just add some padding to the input.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you add some padding:

```
<input type="text" name="test1" value="jj" style="padding:5px;font-size:70px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, padding should resolve the problem but I think that can be more specifically doing a **padding-left** and test values to your desired layout.

For example, with 10px of padding left.

```html
<input type="text" name="test1" value="jj" style="padding-left:10px;font-size:70px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'">
```